# Drug classification database information

Tags: public-databases, data-retrieval, drugs

Is there any database that give information about the drug class. Right now I have all the MeSH id of the drugs from different publications. So right now I'm looking one by one drug looking at the drug description,usage as well as I'm looking at this [MeSh tree structure](https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?name=Mitoxantrone). There are many drug which overlaps mostly due to the core structure . For example Doxorubicin and Aclarubicin both have the same origin which is Anthracyclines. I would like to group them together based on this first.

So Is there any database where I can make query in batches to get my result.

1. drug description
2. usage
3. MeSH tree structure or similar information which gives output about the drugs hierarchical classification.